# Visual Studio Code CSS Support Showing Classes in All File Types

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use a plugin for vscode that shows css styles in the text editor (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css) but after I added bootstrap, the class suggestions show up in every type of file not just html. So I will be working in a c# file and in methods and properties I have the entire list of bootstrap classes showing. How can I get rid of this?

```
"css.remoteStyleSheets": [
    
        "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ],
```